# How do I vertically center align a position:relative element?

Tags: css, alignment, css-position, center

How do I vertically center align the **parent container** to the canvas which has  `position:relative`? The parent container has a child element with `position:absolute`. The child element has been positioned in the center of the parent container.

Here's a snippet:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: auto;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One solution is to wrap your `.container` with two wrappers; give the first one `display: table;` and `height: 100%; width: 100%;` and the second `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;`. Also make sure your `body` and `html` have full height.

Here's a little working demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/exmRf/13/).

Another method is to apply `top: 50%;` to your `.container` and `margin-top: -150px;` (`300px / 2 = 150px`). (Note that this method requires you to know the exact height of your container, so it **might** not be exactly what you want, but it might as well be!). A little working demo of this latter method: [another little link](http://jsfiddle.net/exmRf/17/).

I hope that helped!

Comment: Wow, thanks! It works, just curious, is that the only way to do this? Is this the most elegant way? I am looking for a solution that works in modern browsers. So outdated browsers don't matter to me.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew why body needs to have height: 100% in order for this to work? Any quick answers?

Comment: @Vennsoh Because if you don't specify `height: 100%` to `body`, it will only be large enough to fit the elements, not the full screen. And you want your container to be centered within the full screen, so you need `body` to cover it all.