# Scrolling to see more of fixed div if overflows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a popup modal window that is positioned fixed and with a set width and height. It is also centered on the window:

[image]

It all works fine, except if the window height is reduced far enough, part of the div is cut off, with the user unable to see all of its content:

[image]

Is there a way to add scrolling to the parent container (which is also fixed) to see the rest of the modal/div?

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ttxh6zd2/1/)

```css
*{ margin:0; }

#popup-background
{
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#popup-modal
{
  padding: 20px;
  width:500px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-background">
  <div id="popup-modal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu audiam prodesset sed, vitae recusabo expetenda mei ei. Mei an soluta sententiae, no vim deserunt signiferumque. Sint ocurreret no vim, alia inani dissentias eam cu. Velit oratio quo et. In omnis utinam lobortis qui, usu id deleniti reprehendunt comprehensam.

Mutat vituperatoribus quo et. Facer quodsi temporibus eu qui. Nam choro dicam partiendo te, ex volumus facilisi insolens mel, at sit iriure nostrum tractatos. Cu invidunt invenire pri, per ullum consequuntur ut. Per munere consul cu. Nam quod solum ea, vis nulla elaboraret quaerendum ut, ea qui malis senserit.

Homero ornatus molestiae at vix, usu ut vide conceptam accommodare. Quaestio iracundia in eam. Mel dictas scripta constituto no, no mea idque errem molestie. Per an case fabulas abhorreant, diam fabellas reprimique sea et. Ad constituam vituperatoribus vix, ut habeo legendos temporibus ius.

Iudico eripuit nec no, pri nonumy legendos reformidans id, ei facete sapientem has. Nam no omnes feugiat verterem, ad eos graeco denique. Ad mea errem intellegat. No tale dicta vivendo mei. Ea quo dictas discere, ut saperet epicurei ocurreret mea. Primis intellegat eu est, at vix quem quis iudico, vix ad detraxit delicata qualisque.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hard if child div don't have `position:relative;`, and parent `overflow-y:scroll;`.

Comment: @mokiSRB Hey, I found an answer thanks to this clue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @mokiSRB comment, I changed my modal from being fixed to relative. Then I found [How do I vertically center align a position:relative element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157992/how-do-i-vertically-center-align-a-positionrelative-element), which suggested wrapping the relative div twice with:

```
.wrappert {
    height: 100%; 
    width: 100%;
    display: table;    
}
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

After some more minor tweaks I ended up with: http://jsfiddle.net/senju/ynjn2u7L/

```css
*{ margin:0; }

#popup-background
{
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow-y:auto;
}

#popup-modal
{
  padding: 20px;
  width:500px;
  height: 350px;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.wrappert {
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%;
  display: table;    
}
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;  
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup-background">
  <div class="wrappert">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="popup-modal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu audiam prodesset sed, vitae recusabo expetenda mei ei. Mei an soluta sententiae, no vim deserunt signiferumque. Sint ocurreret no vim, alia inani dissentias eam cu. Velit oratio quo et. In omnis utinam lobortis qui, usu id deleniti reprehendunt comprehensam.

Mutat vituperatoribus quo et. Facer quodsi temporibus eu qui. Nam choro dicam partiendo te, ex volumus facilisi insolens mel, at sit iriure nostrum tractatos. Cu invidunt invenire pri, per ullum consequuntur ut. Per munere consul cu. Nam quod solum ea, vis nulla elaboraret quaerendum ut, ea qui malis senserit.

Homero ornatus molestiae at vix, usu ut vide conceptam accommodare. Quaestio iracundia in eam. Mel dictas scripta constituto no, no mea idque errem molestie. Per an case fabulas abhorreant, diam fabellas reprimique sea et. Ad constituam vituperatoribus vix, ut habeo legendos temporibus ius.

Iudico eripuit nec no, pri nonumy legendos reformidans id, ei facete sapientem has. Nam no omnes feugiat verterem, ad eos graeco denique. Ad mea errem intellegat. No tale dicta vivendo mei. Ea quo dictas discere, ut saperet epicurei ocurreret mea. Primis intellegat eu est, at vix quem quis iudico, vix ad detraxit delicata qualisque.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the css like this

```
*{ margin:0; }

#popup-background
{
position:fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#popup-modal
{
 padding: 20px;
 width:500px;
 max-height: 350px;
height :80%;
background: #EFEFEF;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
overflow-y: auto
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/chauhangs/af142jg9/

Comment: I'd rather not have the contents of the div scrollable, but the container scrollable to view the div. I actually, just found a way of doing it and replied to this question with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the modal be scrollable, but the whole page instead do this:

CSS:

```
.background{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.modal_container{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.modal_wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.modal_content{
    background: white;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 999;
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="modal_container">
    <div class="modal_wrapper">
        <div class="modal_content">
            MY CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But be careful, when opening the modal you should set *overflow:hidden* to the *html* tag, because if you dont you can get 2 scrollbars which looks ugly.