# Vertical centered element leaves empty space on top

Tags: html, css, css-position, vertical-alignment

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157992/how-do-i-vertically-center-align-a-positionrelative-element) thread to vertically center an element on page of my website. It works but leaves large empty space on top and I can't figure out why.

```css
.wrappert {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.cn-container {
  width: 60%;
  /* min-width: 600px; */
  max-width: 820px;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}

.cn-slide{
 text-align: center;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 padding-top: 80px;
 margin: 0 5%;
 width: 90%; /* 738px fixed*/
 opacity: 0;
}

.cn-slide:target{
 opacity: 1;
 z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrappert">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cn-container">
      <div class="cn-slide" id="slide-main">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</divv>
      <div class="cn-slide" id="slide-main">Nam dapibus euismod ex egestas dictum.</divv>
      <div class="cn-slide" id="slide-main">Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</divv>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The website is  http://www.glamparrucchieria.com

Comment: Post your code. But that's what vertically centering does right? It leave a gap above and below it.

Comment: Sure, but the gap should be equal on top and bottom, if it isn't it's not centered

Comment: @Ponzaro, my bad. misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistakenly assuming that your `.cn-slide` elements, with their `position: absolute`, will participate in normal flow of layout, expanding their container height and distributing extra space at the top and bottom, if necessary. They will *not* do those things -- they are absolutely positioned and do not contribute to the size of your `.cn-container` element. It's almost as if they are not there at all.

That's why you see what you see -- the height of `.cn-container` is zero and the slides are just hanging visually where they would have been if they were statically positioned. And if you specified `left`, `top`, `right`, or `bottom`, you'd be moving them around freely, with nearest absolutely or relatively positioned ancestor element (or corner of the document) for pivot.

It's a bit as if you had one visual transparent layer for each slide on top of one another and all in front of the rest of your page, if you can imagine that.

Your safest bet is to abandon absolute positioning by removing `position: absolute` from your `.cn-slide` rule, and apply `display: none` to those "inactive" slides of yours that need to be hidden from view, only showing that one "active" slide (`:target`) with `display: block`:

```
.cn-slide {
     display: none; /** 'disable' each slide */
     position: initial; /** or just make sure there is no absolute positioning, this is just to illustrate static positioning, if you don't have `position: absolute` applying for this selector, you don't need this rule. */
}
.cn-slide:target {
     display: block; /** enable the 'current' slide */ 
}
```

Incorporating the equivalent of the above, your page should look like you want it to. And remember that absolute positioning creates something like a new layer in front or behind other page elements, simply speaking. Read the ["CSS basic box model"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box) if you want to learn the theory.