# Error with z-index on video not allowing buttons and text to be shown

Tags: html, css, z-index

My website is dommazzola.com

I have a video that automatically plays along with two action buttons and description that are suppose to display on top of the video. unfortunately, they are hiding behind the video.. The video and buttons (.description and .title) have different z-index's. The buttons seem to load at first, but then hide behind the video.

Here is my CSS file and HTML:

HTML

```
  <div class="homepage-hero-module">
  <div class="video-container">
    <div class="title-container">
      <div class="headline">
        <h1>Landscaping Taken Seriously</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="description">
        <div class="inner">Lexington Lawncare’s Landscaping has thrived because of a commitment to creating exceptional outdoor living environments.</div>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success mt-2" href="#" role="button">Contact Us</a><span>  </span><a class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-success px-4 mt-2" href="#customer-logo-slider" role="button">Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="filter"></div>
    <!-- #TODO: NEED WEBM VIDEO FOR THIS TO WORK ON FIREFOX -->
    <video autoplay loop muted poster="static/images/slider12.jpg" class="fillWidth">
      <source src="https://d2cd6p07f07ng7.cloudfront.net/IMG_3036.mp4" type="video/mp4" />Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.homepage-hero-module {
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: relative;
}
.no-video .video-container video,
.touch .video-container video {
  display: none;
}
.no-video .video-container .poster,
.touch .video-container .poster {
  display: block !important;
}
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  height: 100%; /* was 100% */
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #000;
}
.video-container .poster img {
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.video-container .filter {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: 100%;
}
.video-container .title-container {
  z-index: 1000;
  margin-top: 32rem;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .headline {
  font-size: 3em; /* added */
}
.video-container .description .inner {
  font-size: 1.35em; /* was 1em */
  width: 50%; /* was 45% */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container .link {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1001;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container .link a {
  color: #fff;
}
.video-container video {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.video-container video.fillWidth {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this css

```
.video-container .title-container{
    position: relative;
}
```

result
[image]

Comment: it is set to relative

Comment: may be not, check your css

Comment: This fix works when I try it. I can indeed not find the position relative either.

Comment: Whats the best way to move the text description and title elements to the middle of the video without just calling a bootstrap margin?

Comment: well, then you need to made few changes,that is difficult to explain, i creted css related to your code

Comment: i got this solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157992/how-do-i-vertically-center-align-a-positionrelative-element?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `position: relative`to your `title-container` class. This will allow your `z-index` to display properly. `z-index` only applies to positioned elements

Comment: My bad, i didn't paste my CSS correctly. I have that